# When I try to install Ubuntu 12.10 from a disk, the install crashes

Tags: installation, 12.10, dual-boot

I'm trying to run ubuntu 12.10 alongside windows 7, so that if one os crashes I have a backup.  My machine is 64 bit intel celeron, i think 900ghz.  Whenever I selected "install ubuntu" from the dvd options at startup and got to the page where it said "run alongside windows" and "replace windows."  Whenever I select "run alongside windows," the screen flashes black, shows the ubuntu starting up/shutting down screen, and the progress bar does not move.  After a couple minutes of not doing anything, the disk ejects.  What exactly is happening to cause this?

-Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told its a Intel Celeron machine 900Mhz(I think Ghz is too much :) ) and its the entry-level processor. And you're already running an OS like Windows 7. The processor don't have the capability of running two OS side by side. You can run only one OS at a time on processor like that.

Comment: Thanks!  I know that wubi installs ubuntu so that you use grub to select which OS you want to boot.  Is there any way to do that with a disk, since "install ubuntu inside windows" doesn't work?  Also, I've looked at trying to install ubuntu on a partition, but I can't make sense of the partition tool on the boot disk, where could I find a Rosetta stone for what everything means?